# How to make favicon animation loop continuously?

Tags: animated-gif

I am using a favicon on my site with 30 frames for the animation. After the favicon 30th frame plays, the animation stops.

I need the favicon to loop continuously. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your gif icon is not set for looping. download UnFREEze and check you favicon for loop. look at [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Animated-Favicons) for step by step tutorial.